# Will too many $_SESSION on a website affect/interfere with each other

Tags: php, mysql, session

I have a website with 3 pages, while each page has articles that are dynamically displayed from the database, and each has a specific `article_id (int)`.. To make the comments for each `article_id` display very well, i decided to store the `article_id` in a `$_SESSION` while inserting comments into the db.

My problem now is that i'll be having many more articles and `$SESSION` for each article/comments, will they not interfere with each other or mis function in the future?

Thanks

**Problem To Which I Need The SESSION**

http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/10486305/variable-returning-0-instead-of-an-actual-value/10486418#comment13552062_10486418

Comment: Well making too much session variables is not recommended why don't you unset after they do their work ?

Comment: Will this not affect the $_SESSION['username'] i have on the script? Or is there a way to do this for a single variable.

Comment: Why don't you pass the article id as hidden field in the form where people comment? Username will be in session.

Comment: @itachi....pls how can i implement your suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

although it does not answer your qestion, but here is how you should be dealing with.

since you need the `article_id` while posting comment, and the article is being fetched from database. while fetching create an hidden input field like

```
<input type="hidden" name="article_id" value="<?php //article_id  ?>"/>
```

and then while submitting the comment place this hidden field inside the comment form, and you will get the `article_id`.

**Update:** 
here is how you should decide what to use and when.

**a)** when you need to send some variable with values from one page to another page with the purpose of maintaining the state between them. for example in one page you have displayed chunks of articles and when user clicks on `read more...` you want to display them the full article with comments section. then you should probably use an anchor tag here. for example `<a href="articledetail.php?id=2">Read More...</a>` and in `articledetail.php` page you can use php's `$_GET` to fetch the url in an array. in this case the value will be `$_GET['id'] = 1`

**b)** use session only when you need something that should be accessible in your application as a whole not for maintaining the state like above(this case does not apply to AJAX based pages). for example you should use session to check if the user is logged in or not, or to store the user information like user id, username etc. since logically a user will be the one who will browse your application and you may sometimes need to access some information related to user in most of the pages. SESSION suits here.

**c)** hidden fields `<input type="hidden" name="article_id" value="<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>"/>` 
 should be used when you want to send some hidden value for example via `$_POST` to insert into the database.

hope this helps you.

Comment: What I need the article_id for is to INSERT it's value in the db for any comment made, and also to display it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

in the comment form, make a hidden input.

```
<input type="hidden" name="article_id" value = "<?php echo $row['article_id'];?>"/>
```

This `$row['article_id']` will come from the query which you used for the showing the article.

Then on Submit the form, The article id will appear in `$_POST['article_id']`. Then use the `Insert` query putting those values.

In this approach, you will need only 1 session variable. i.e. `$_SESSION['username']`.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have hundreds and hundreds of session variables, or store hundreds of bytes in the session. otherwise most more processor will be able to handle the load.

Basically, the default session handler of php stores the session variables in a file per session. And loads it each time a request with the session cookie arrives. so if your session is used to store a few gigs of data, it will be loaded at every page.