# Insert the correct value to the database table instead of 0

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm making a simple webshop for my university project that uses two tables from database (users and items).
I try to insert into the database some information about the specific item. The last column is the id of the logged user. I make query that receiving from 'users' table the id of the actually logged user.
When I use this variable ($lastlogin) printing via echo it shows a correct value.
Unfortunately when I try to insert the id to the table 'items' with insert query, there goes 0 instead of the correct value (eg. 5).
Does anyone know how to fix my problem? I will be grateful.

```
$idlogin = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE login=:login";
$query = $db->prepare($idlogin);

$query->bindParam(":login", $_SESSION['login']);
$query->execute();
$row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$lastlogin = $row["id"];

$sql = "INSERT INTO `items` VALUES (NULL, :name, :description, :cust_id)";
$params = [ ":name" => trim($_POST["name"]),
            ":description" => trim($_POST["description"]),
            ":cust_id" => '$lastlogin'];
$query = $db->prepare($sql);
$query->execute($params);
```

Comment: Is there more than one row with the same login value but different user id's?

Comment: have you tried `var_dump($lastlogin)` to make sure a user id is definitely being retrieved?

Comment: @SteveKnau - No, every login is unique, I've made a nickname validation in registration script ;)

Comment: @scottevans93 - yes, echo shows **string(1) "4" **
but when I use (int)var_dump($lastlogin)
it adds 0 to the end like **string(1) "4" 0**

Comment: @Michal Try `":cust_id" => intval($lastlogin)`

Comment: @scottevans93 Unfortunately query still inserting 0 (when int) or NULL (when $lastlogin is string)

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to put `$lastlogin` between quotes in your params. If you do, mysql will see this as a string with the value `"$lastlogin"`. Mysql won't be able to parse this to an integer and add the value `0` instead.

```
$params = [ 
    ":name" => trim($_POST["name"]),
    ":description" => trim($_POST["description"]),
    ":cust_id" => $lastlogin
];
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. There is a progress. Now the query inserts NULLs, as if the variable is not keeping value.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks for everyone who tried to help me

I found a clue in Michael Berkowski response at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10486305/variable-returning-0-instead-of-an-actual-value)
$lastlogin was initialized only the first time, so I put it into $_SESSION['lastlogin'] and call it in sql query.

```
$idlogin = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE login=:login";
$query = $db->prepare($idlogin);
$query->bindParam(":login", $_SESSION['login']);
$query->execute();
$row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$lastlogin = (int)$row["id"];
$_SESSION['lastlogin'] = $lastlogin;

$sql = "INSERT INTO items VALUES (NULL, :name, :description, :cust_id)";

$params = [ 
    ":name" => trim($_POST["name"]),
    ":description" => trim($_POST["description"]),
    ":cust_id" => $_SESSION['lastlogin']
];
$query = $db->prepare($sql);
$query->execute($params);
```

Now everything works great. Thanks again for your time.